# Recurrence Relation for Lunch Order

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

> Each day Angela eats lunch at a deli, ordering one of the following: chicken salad, a tuna sandwich, or a turkey wrap. Find a recurrence relation for the number of ways for her to order lunch for the $n$ days if she never orders chicken salad three days in a row.

I found a solution here: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080518143728AAmAnM5

I am trying to understand it.

For $n=5$, why are there $6$ choices for aaa-- and --aaa?

I have:

aaabb, aaacc, aaabc, aaacb

Where do the other two possibilities come from?

Comment: $aaaba$ and $aaaca$ are also valid choices since in these choices she isn't ordering chicken salad three days _in a row_.

Comment: @ThomasBladt ahhhh i dont know why i didnt think of that...thank you